# New line or line break in HTML generated from XML

Tags: html, xml

I have a string in XML that should be separated by new lines when it is viewed on a webpage generated from XML.

**Goal**

*Hello Alice,*

*My name is Bob.*

**Failed Attempts**

```
<description>Hello Alice, 
My name is Bob.
</description>
```

*Hello Alice, My name is Bob*

```
<description>Hello Alice, \n
My name is Bob.
</description>
```

*Hello Alice, \nMy name is Bob*

```
<description>Hello Alice, &#xA;&#xD;
My name is Bob.
</description>
```

*Hello Alice,   My name is Bob.*

```
<description><![CDATA[Hello Alice,<br />
My name is Bob.]]>
</description>
```

*Hello Alice,`<br />`My name is Bob.*

Is this possible, assuming that I have no control over how the HTML is generated from the XML file (i.e. I am only able to edit the XML)? If possible, how can I produce the line break?

I noticed a lot of very similar questions, but I haven't found a solution (if there exists one). Sorry in advance if this seems to be a duplicate. Also, thanks in advance!

Comment: the last failed attempt should have worked... but if you're testing just the line, maybe it fails because of lack of `html - body` tag so it can interpret them

Comment: I think it actually depends on how it is generated. If you are in fact just reading the string, and outputting it as HTML, the last one without the CDATA should work just fine. If you are using a built in library, then you may want to check the instructions of that library.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath In the one you mentioned, it appears as though &#xA;&#xD; becomes two spaces as a result. Does this give any ideas?

Comment: @Sandy Are you expecting one space? and do you have your own logic for parsing, or using an existing library?

Comment: @surgeonofdeath No, I'm not expecting a single space instead. In other words I am getting space(s) instead of a line break. I thought this might hint something about the code that is generating the HTML.

Comment: @Sandy, as you did not provide the information about the parser logic, nor the library, I can only assume it parses according to the known standards. You should try &#x0A; with the 0, and you can also try &lt;br /&gt;

Comment: Do you realize that your **Goal** is being rendered on one line?  Is that really your goal?   HTML will do the same thing in that a newline alone will not render as a new line; you need `br` tag (or other markup/CSS).

Comment: @kjhughes thanks. I didn't notice! Made the edit.

Comment: @surgeonofdeath thanks, I'll try your suggestion. I'm modifying some existing project so I don't know what library or parsing logic is used yet. Finding the answer to that now.